# Android notification pops up at random times

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to pop up notification at the time that user selects and repeat ir every day at the same time. I set up notification like this:

NotifyActivity:

```
public void setAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(NotifyActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotifyActivity.this, 1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Message Sent!").setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("TITLE");
    alert.setMessage("Notification was set.");
    alert.show();
}
```

AlarmReciever:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "NotificationService");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
```

AlarmService:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("TITLE");
    builder.setContentText("TEXT");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "NotificationService");
    wakeLock.acquire(10000);
    WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyCpuLock");
    wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    wakeLock.release();

    //set next alarm after 24 hours
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 1, alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 86400000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Everything is fine. I get notification at the time I set. But also get the same notification at random times. How can I get rid of those random notifications? Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I have updated my code and set alarm to simple not to setRepeating. I set new alarm in the service when old notification pops up. But I still get a notification at a random time. First notification pops up at the time I have set and others pops up not after 24 hours but after a few hours, 40 minutes or other random time. I have tried to set alarmManager.setExact it comes only from api 19, but I had the same problem. My targetSdkVersion set to 18 now.

EDIT 2: And it also throws more than one notification if I set alarm only in NotifyActivity and delete last five lines of AlarmService. I think it should throw only one.

Answer (score 0):

If it is intended to not wake up the phone, then ignore the text below (tho, I think wakelocks can be useful for your app anyway). If u want to make the app to work even when phone sleeps then read it also:

Try using RTC_WAKE_UP instead of RTC. When phone sleeps it will not wake up that way.

Also I see u can have problem with staying your phone awake. It can go to sleep before service has done it's work.
Use [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or create [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in     onReceive().
This will make sure that ur phone is awake during service.

WakefulBroadcastReceiver is the best option for the 2nd thing, about wakelocks - u can check on google some examples that show how to use alarm manager with wakelocks.
Ofc, ur service can done it's work, but sometimes sleep can occour, so I suggest you to implement it even if ur tests don't show the problem, better too keep it safe.

EDIT:

Checked furher, u can use     PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT instead of    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, but not in the pending where u set up alarm, but there where u set up ur notify. It should work just fine!

EDIT 2:

Also I advice you to change request number. Pending intents will not be overrided that way.

For example:

In AlarmService:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

In setAlarm():

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotifyActivity.this, 1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I am not sure how these two work together, it is possible they can be not overrided, but I thinkit can be safer to do that way.
If you would want to create more pending intents to be not overrided u can use SharedPreferences to keep int number or date base int, incrementing each time when Pending Intent is created and put it as argument in them. In my app it works fine.

Comment: Will I get notification after a day if FLAG_ONE_SHOT is used?

Comment: Oh, yea it will not, ofc, my fault, sorry.
I will delete it from answer as it is wrong answer for repeating alarms.

I will look further in code and try to help you.

I think you can use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead.

But note that in ur application only 1 Pending intent can running, due to request number

Comment: Checked furher, u can use FLAG_ONE_SHOT but not in the pending where u set up alarm, but there where u set up ur notify. It should work just fine!

Comment: I have thought that everything is ok too soon. I got the random notification again. I have edited my post and updated my code.

Comment: Create some logs, it will be useful and test application. It looks like there is no problem with Pending being alive after being fired, I think it might be called few times. Check it by creating log before creating the notification. If Notifity class is being called few times (not regullary) it will be easier to spot the problem

Comment: I have updated my question. And I call NotifyClass setAlarm method only on button click.

Comment: okay, I went through your code, but can't find a problem. Pls, create logs before in onReceive and before creating notifications. We will see if there is a problem in broadcasting or in notification system.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) states that "as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact".

Maybe that's whats causing the issue?

Comment: I can test it. If I set targetSdkVersion to 18. It should work, right?

Comment: I can't see anything really wrong with your code, try logging your calls to setAlarm() to see if you accidentally call the function more that once.
Also try rebooting your phone to make sure that these alarms are not left over from any previous builds.